# Get extra field via annotate in Django many to many relation

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-annotate

I have a m2m relation between a `Feature` model and the `User` model through an intermediary table. Feature model represents all the available features, and a User can enable or disable zero, one or more of them via web or api. When a user enables a feature the corresponding record is created in the intermediary table, when the user disables a feature the record is deleted.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Feature(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='FeatureUserM2M')
    ...other fields...

class FeatureUserM2M(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    feature = models.ForeignKey(Feature, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...other fields...
```

Supposing data like so

```
Feature            User          Intermediary
|id|name        |  |id|name   |  |id|user_id|feature_id|
+--+------------+  +--+-------+  +--+-------+----------+
|1 |feature foo |  |1 |user A |  |1 |2      |1         |
|2 |feature bar |  |2 |user B |  |  |       |          |
|3 |feature baz |  |  |       |  |  |       |          |
```

I need a result with all the available features, and for a given user, another field indicating if the user has the feature enabled or not (could be a boolean). Ideally, for "user A", the result I need is like:

```
|user_id|feature_id|enabled |
+-------+----------+--------+
|2      |1         | true   |
|2      |2         | false  |
|2      |3         | false  |
```

I tried

```py
Feature.objects.annotate(enabled=Subquery(
    FeatureUserM2M.objects.filter(
        feature=OuterRef('pk'),
        user=request.user,
    )
))
*** django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field
```

I don't think the query I did is right, but even specifying the output type as `BooleanField` I don't have what I want.

```py
Feature.objects.annotate(enabled=Subquery(
    FeatureUserM2M.objects.filter(
        feature=OuterRef('pk'),
        user=request.user,
    )), output_field=BooleanField
)
*** TypeError: QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): <class 'django.db.models.fields.BooleanField'>.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you can just use an `Exists()` subquery. An example and description of it is in the documentation here:

[**Subqueries - Exists**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries)

```
Feature.objects.annotate(enabled=Exists(
    FeatureUserM2M.objects.filter(
        feature=OuterRef('pk'),
        user=request.user,
    )
))
```

However, you were pretty close to the correct answer, all I did was read a bit further into the docs and replaced your `Subquery` with `Exists` :)

The reason your second attempt resulted in an error which could have been correct, would be fixed like so:

```
Feature.objects.annotate(enabled=Subquery(
    FeatureUserM2M.objects.filter(
        feature=OuterRef('pk'),
        user=request.user,
    ), output_field=BooleanField) # <-- moved the parenthesis
)
```

This is described in the documentation here:

[**Subqueries**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Subquery)

Where you can specify the keyword argument `output_field` as you were trying to do, but actually you placed it inside the `.annotate(...)`

But im not entirely convinced it would be the same resulting output as `Exists(...)` though having said that.